# Why can event listeners stop working after using element.innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, innerhtml

I am a beginner in JavaScript. A JavaScript book says that one of disadvantages of `element.innerHTML` is:

> Event handlers may no longer work as intended.

I can't understand what this mean. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Here is an array/JSON analogy: `var obj = [Infinity]; var str = JSON.stringify(obj); str = str.slice(0, -1) + ', 42]'; obj = JSON.parse(str);`. This is a very horrible way of adding a new element to the array. The result is the array `[null, 42]` because JSON cannot represent `Infinity`. Similarly for DOM, any event handlers bound to an element will be lost if it is converted to HTML because HTML itself cannot store a representation of the bound functions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most probably, it refers to the technique some people use to insert HTML at the end:

```
element.innerHTML += "inserted HTML";
```

This will get the current HTML, concatenate it with the inserted one, and parse it all.

As a side effect, all the internal state of the existing elements (like event listeners, checkedness, ...) will be lost.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.textContent = "I won't work anymore";
  document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Inserted text</p>";
});
```

```html
<button>Click me to insert HTML</button>
```

Instead, if you want to insert some HTML at the end of an element, you can use

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "inserted HTML");
```

This will preserve the existing elements.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.textContent = "I still work";
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>Inserted text</p>");
});
```

```html
<button>Click me to insert HTML</button>
```

Another alternative, if you don't mind the inserted content to be wrapped inside an element, is using `appendChild`:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.textContent = "I still work";
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.innerHTML = "<p>Inserted text</p>";
  document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
});
```

```html
<button>Click me to insert HTML</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML`  is a *string representation* of html contents of an *element*. Getting these contents has no side effect but resetting it force the browser to generate *new* elements.

Each HTML tag in a document is parsed as an unique DOM HTMLElement object by the browsers. Event handlers are bound to these elements. By resetting `innerHTML` property, browser removes the old elements and makes the DOM parser to create other element objects based on the new html string. When an element is removed it's event handlers are also removed.

Imagine that you have an element that responds to it's click events via a handler, when the element is removed you can't click on it so it makes you feel the handler is also removed. The way event handlers are garbage collected depends on the code that has been written and the way a JavaScript interpreter works.

Answer (score -1):

Because when you dynamically create an element with Javascript with the element.innerHTML function, the newly created element might not respond to Event Listeners methods as intended.