# ajax reload ul/li div and retain event listeners (other than insertAdjacentHTML)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, livereload, insertadjacenthtml

**Goal**: reload only the div after ajax calls (add or remove tags) without losing event listeners on the reloaded div. Using `insertAdjacentHTML` does not seem optimal.

**Front-end**: I have a sidebar with ul/li for tags. There's a modal to add/create tags; there is an icon "X" next to each tag to remove it on click.

```
<ul>
  <li><span>A</span><span class=li-untag>X</span> 
  <li><span>B</span><span class=li-untag>X</span> 
  <li><span>C</span><span class=li-untag>X</span> 
  <li><span>D</span><span class=li-untag>X</span>
</ul>
```

**My failed setup was**:

1. send an ajax (fetch) call to the php back-end to add or remove tags
2. if no error, the back-end sends an updated and twig-formatted list of tags for the article
3. updated the div with `innerHTML`.

The `innerHTML` update would lose all the event listeners of the list (such as remove tag when clicking X) until a real refresh of the page. I tried to run the addeventlisteners after the ajax call but it didn't work.

**My current setup** based on previous SO answers (see below) uses `insertAdjacentHTML`. That (sort of) works, but it's clunky.

- to *remove* a tag is not an insert issue and all I could think of was to hide a tag on click until the page is refreshed.
- to *add* tags with `insertAdjacentHTML` is to append new tags to the list, but it's no longer alphabetically ordered and I have to use some hacky javascript to format the output to match the existing list.

I would really prefer having php send a whole updated and formatted list for the div.

Any suggestions for a more elegant way to do this in vanilla js?

> FYI: The main answers I have relied on:
>   [Why can event listeners stop working after using element.innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448622/why-can-event-listeners-stop-working-after-using-element-innerhtml])
>   [Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list])
>   [If a DOM Element is removed, are its listeners also removed from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory])
>   [JS eventListener click disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040431/js-eventlistener-click-disappearing])

**Edit**: the listener is attached to the "li-untag" class

**Edit 2**: answering the comment request for some more code. Here is for the removing tag, using the [atomic ajax library](https://github.com/cferdinandi/atomic):

```
for(let liUntag of document.querySelectorAll('.li-untag')){
liUntag.addEventListener("click", () => altUntag(liUntag))};

const altUntag = (el) => {
    atomic("/tags", {
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            type: 'untag',
            slug: el.getAttribute('data-slug'),
            tag: el.getAttribute('data-untag')
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        el.closest('li').style.display = 'none';
        console.log(response.data); // xhr.responseText
        console.log(response.xhr);  // full response
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.status); // xhr.status
        console.log(error.statusText); // xhr.statusText
    });
};
```

Comment: Where exactly is the listener attached to, the `<ul>`? Then just replace the `<ul>`'s `innerHTML`, and it should stay attached. If you attach a listener to a child element that you replace, then the listener will be lost, as expected (I'd avoid that, use event delegation instead)

Comment: can you show the php/js code?

Comment: In the actual code it's attached to the icon with the class "li-untag" but here it's just an "X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *best* solution for something like this would be to use event delegation to attach a single listener to the `ul` instead of attaching multiple listeners to each `li-untag`:

```
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('.li-untag')) {
    target.closest('li').remove();
  }
});
```

If you don't want to do that and want to keep a listener on each `li-untag` element, you can insert the new HTML, then sort the `<li>`s, and attach listeners to each new `li-untag`:

```
const addListeners = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.li-untag').forEach((span) => {
    span.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
      target.closest('ul').remove();
    });
  });
};

// on document load:
addListeners();

// after inserting new HTML:
const lis = [...document.querySelectorAll('ul li')];
lis.sort((a, b) => a.children[0].textContent.localeCompare(b.children[0].textContent));
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
lis.forEach((li) => {
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
addListeners();
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try it and report back